# Need help on uploading audio and pdf files with php

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm stuck with file uploading problem.

I've searched for answers but found only "increasing post_max_size and upload_max_filesize" suggestion and that doesn't work for me.

I can't get large files uploaded (approx. 20MB)Files smaller than 8MB work fine, but anything larger seems to not work... I am not getting any error message but when the upload finishes, the screen is blank and file is not found in the uploads directory, the following are my php.ini settings and my environments

```
max_input_time -1
max_execution_time 600
memory_limit 512M
upload_max_filesize 100M
post_max_size 100M
```

So, any ideas on what happen in this? I’m really stuck here can’t get this problem solve.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for file upload

```
<?php
    $allowedExts = array("pdf", "mp3");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "pdf")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "mp3")
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
              {
                  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
              }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000
```

20000 is approx. 20KB not 20MB